# Jquery Wrap a div around first 5 elements and another div around last elements

Tags: jquery

I have this example code and I would like to hide all the content rows > 5 and add a link to show/hide more.

```
<div class="wb-allview-cat-cnt wb-col-xs-12 wb-col-sm-12 wb-col-md-3">
    <div class="wb-row">
        <div class="wb-col-md-12">Content</div>
        <div class="wb-col-md-12">Content</div>
        <div class="wb-col-md-12">Content</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="wb-allview-cat-cnt wb-col-xs-12 wb-col-sm-12 wb-col-md-3">
    <div class="wb-row">
        <div class="wb-col-md-12">Content</div>
        <div class="wb-col-md-12">Content</div>
        <div class="wb-col-md-12">Content</div>
        <div class="wb-col-md-12">Content</div>
        <div class="wb-col-md-12">Content</div>
        <div class="wb-col-md-12">Content</div>
        <div class="wb-col-md-12">Content</div>
        <div class="wb-col-md-12">Content</div>
        <div class="wb-col-md-12">Content</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="wb-allview-cat-cnt wb-col-xs-12 wb-col-sm-12 wb-col-md-3">
    <div class="wb-row">
        <div class="wb-col-md-12">Content</div>
        <div class="wb-col-md-12">Content</div>
        <div class="wb-col-md-12">Content</div>
        <div class="wb-col-md-12">Content</div>
        <div class="wb-col-md-12">Content</div>
        <div class="wb-col-md-12">Content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried this but it's not working, kind of got stuck here

```
$('.wb-row > div:lt(5)').wrapAll('<div class="first5"></div>');
```

Comment: If you want to "hide all the content rows > 5" then why are you doing `div:lt(5)`? Wouldn't you want `div:gt(4)`

Comment: I'm just trying out some stuff to see what works, maybe i'd wrap a div around first and last and show/hide these... If anyone has better solution help is welcome :)

Comment: Like this -> **https://jsfiddle.net/ggeaacuz/**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you need to use `:gt(4)` to `hide()`. You can `append()` an `a` element which you hook a click event handler to which then shows all the sibling `div` elements in that `.wb-row`, something like this:

```js
$('.wb-row').each(function() {
  var $row = $(this),
    $divs = $row.find('.wb-col-md-12');

  if ($divs.length >= 5) {
    $divs.filter(':gt(4)').hide();
    $row.append('<a href="#" class="show-more">Show more...</a>');
  }
});

$('.wb-row').on('click', '.show-more', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).text(function(i, t) {
    return t == 'Show more...' ? 'Hide' : 'Show more...';
  }).siblings('div:gt(4)').toggle();
});
```

```css
.wb-row {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wb-allview-cat-cnt wb-col-xs-12 wb-col-sm-12 wb-col-md-3">
  <div class="wb-row">
    <div class="wb-col-md-12">Content</div>
    <div class="wb-col-md-12">Content</div>
    <div class="wb-col-md-12">Content</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wb-allview-cat-cnt wb-col-xs-12 wb-col-sm-12 wb-col-md-3">
  <div class="wb-row">
    <div class="wb-col-md-12">Content</div>
    <div class="wb-col-md-12">Content</div>
    <div class="wb-col-md-12">Content</div>
    <div class="wb-col-md-12">Content</div>
    <div class="wb-col-md-12">Content</div>
    <div class="wb-col-md-12">Content</div>
    <div class="wb-col-md-12">Content</div>
    <div class="wb-col-md-12">Content</div>
    <div class="wb-col-md-12">Content</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wb-allview-cat-cnt wb-col-xs-12 wb-col-sm-12 wb-col-md-3">
  <div class="wb-row">
    <div class="wb-col-md-12">Content</div>
    <div class="wb-col-md-12">Content</div>
    <div class="wb-col-md-12">Content</div>
    <div class="wb-col-md-12">Content</div>
    <div class="wb-col-md-12">Content</div>
    <div class="wb-col-md-12">Content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems to work great here on snippet, but I i use it on my code it's hiding all but the first and showing doesn't work.

It's probably because i have more divs inside these <div class="wb-col-md-12">Content</div>

I think this line:     $divs = $row.find('div'); should only target the direct children?

Comment: I updated the code to use the `.wb-col-md-12` class - however that's not really ideal as that's a presentation class. This means that if you change the column widths you'll have to change the JS which isn't ideal.

Comment: It seems to be working fine on your site in Chrome 59

Comment: My bad, css was breaking up my view, it's working great, thank you!